# Passing parent id in nesting form in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, erb

**Target**: save comment for idea model.

**Form:**

```
<%= form_for([@idea, IdeaComment.new], :validate => true) do |f| %>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <%= f.text_area :text, :placeholder => 'some text', :rows => 5 %>
                <%= validate_errors(IdeaComment.new) %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <%= f.button 'Comment', :class => 'button grad-green', :type => 'submit' %>
    <% end %>
```

**Controller:**

```
 @idea_comment = IdeaComment.new(params[:idea_comment])
 ...
```

But if we take a look for params hash:
[image]

How to pass idea_id to "idea_comment"?

Comment: You don't need to do that. Why are you trying to?

Comment: When I try to save my model with params[:idea_comment] there is an error, that idea_id couldn't be null.

Comment: show the code for that? You're probably doing something like `IdeaComment.create(params[:idea_comment])`, instead of `@idea.idea_comments.create(params[:idea_comment])`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Client-side validation is conflicting with resource-oriented forms. Use regular server-side validation instead.

### Explanation:

Resource-oriented forms post to a path based on nested resources:

```
form_for([@idea, IdeaComment.new]) # => POST '/ideas/[:idea_id]/idea_comments'
```

Rails extracts `:idea_id` from the request path and passes it in as a parameter. In the `create` action, the association is set by direct assignment prior to saving:

```
# controllers/idea_comments_controller.rb
def create
  @idea_comment = IdeaComment.new(params[:idea_comment])
  @idea_comment.idea_id = params[:idea_id]
  # ...
  @idea_comment.save
end
```

The problem with **client-side validation** is that it will fail and block form submission until `@idea_comment.idea_id` is assigned, which doesn't happen until *after* the form is submitted.